# Working with AxOWC11.AxSpreadsheet Context Menu

Tags: c#

How can i disable some of the menus like cut, paste, Insert new Row/Column in `AxOWC11.AxSpreadsheet` right click menu, i am using the below code but not getting correct solution from it

```
void spreadSheet_BeforeContextMenu(object sender, 
                         AxOWC11.ISpreadsheetEventSink_BeforeContextMenuEvent e)
{
    //Here i am getting all the menu items but not able to disable it....
    //e.menu
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using below events my problem solved

```
private void spreadSheet_BeforeContextMenu(object sender, AxOWC11.ISpreadsheetEventSink_BeforeContextMenuEvent e) 
{ 
 e.cancel.Value = true; 
} 

private void spreadSheet_StartEdit(object sender, AxOWC11.ISpreadsheetEventSink_StartEditEvent e) 
{ 
 e.cancel.Value = true; 
} 

private void spreadSheet_BeforeKeyDown(object sender, AxOWC11.ISpreadsheetEventSink_BeforeKeyDownEvent e) 
{ 
 if (e.keyCode != 67)//Ctrl + C 
 { 
  e.cancel.Value = true; 
 }
}
```